# error on sending mail while test sending mail successfully in Django

Tags: django

I'm coding about `Forget Password` feature on Django. Reset mail will be sent when user fill out form and click Reset button. But I have a trouble here, mail isn't sent after user click button. I use `sendtestmail` command, sending mail successfully. And more, the content and mail subject that I define is not in the email it sent when I check by `sendtestmail` command. It took me all yesterday to fix above error but didn't work. Can somebody help me.

## settings.py

```
...
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_USER', 'vuthehuy.hus@gmail.com')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD', 'my_password_app')
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = os.getenv('DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL', 'Colo Shop <no-reply@localhost>')
```

## app.urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('password_reset/', auth_view.PasswordResetView.as_view(
        template_name='account/password_reset_form.html',
        form_class=EmailForgotPassword,
        email_template_name='account/password_reset_email.html',
        subject_template_name='account/password_reset_subject.txt'
    ), name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/done/', auth_view.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
        template_name='account/password_reset_done.html'
    ), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password_reset/confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_view.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
        template_name='account/password_change.html'
    ), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password_reset/complete/', auth_view.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
        template_name='account/password_change_done.html'
    ), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

Comment: 1. Have you tried sending with the console backend?

Comment: 2. Have you checked your Gmail account for emails about security issues?

Comment: @MatthewGaiser you meant check with console backend? I have checked fully my Gmail security

Comment: Yes, do you see the email being sent through the console backend?

Comment: I don't see, maybe I get error this??